# How to update Open Java 17 on my linux machine -- need to

Tags: java, linux

I've dabbled with Linux in the past, but my MB pro is dying -- started yesterday, in fact -- and it's time to switch. I have experience with the command line in the Terminal app, so most of the commands -- at least the basic ones -- I'm familiar with in Linux.

I 'm running elementary OS, and was able to download and install the Open JDK for Java 17. I'm working on a project as a way of learning Java. I have a folder labeled "Contacts Java Classes", and I know how to get to the folder, etc. There's a file that I want to run which contains the main method to get things going -- 'MainWIndow.java'

I can compile the file. Before when I tried to run the file w/o compiling I got this error:

```
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class MainWindow
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: MainWindow has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 62.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 61.0
```

After compiling the file, and trying to run it I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2393)
at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:755)
at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1953)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:388)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:232)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:174)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.findFromPaths(NativeLibraries.java:315)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:285)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2398)
at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818)
at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1989)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1392)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1390)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1389)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.initStatic(Toolkit.java:1427)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1401)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:624)
at MainWindow.<init>(MainWindow.java:10)
at MainWindow.main(MainWindow.java:52)
```

Everything works fine on my MB Pro. But even thought I've dabbled before in Linux -- and I just mean dabble, since I always had my OS X -- I'm not sure what's going on.

Should I upgrade to Java 18? And if so, what's the best way to do it? Can anyone help me out? I'v been on other forums, but I'm not sure what I need to sak, and I think I may have gotten under some people's skin. The installing on OS X is easy, but it's more complicated here in Linux, and I'm not sure where to go.

I currently have the open JDK version, but there are versions on Oracle's site (Are they the same thing?). I tried downloading and installing them once last December, but I wasn't sure how to proceed, which versions I needed, and it was somewhat confusing trying to find the answers on the web.

Please offer me any assistance if you can. I wish to stress that my knowledge of Linux is very slight at this point, and I just want to get Java going on it, while I learn more about Linux.  Does that make sense?

Comment: So, that class was compiled originally in Java 18 and you tried to run it in 17, which is why it didn't work. So yes, you can recompile it in 17 then run it. There should be no problem working with 17

Comment: What is "elementary OS"? How did you install Java?

Comment: Just looked it up and it says it's based on Ubuntu, so you should be installing Java with `apt` and, if you have multiple versions installed, selecting one with `update-alternatives`.

Comment: I tried recompiling in java 17, but no luck.  The error messages I got was what I posted.

Comment: can you direct me or let me know how to udpate to 18 with this command?  I'm not sure I follow.  Do you mean I can simply enter a command and it will just update to version 18?